# By default, apply form-control and input-sm css to all input / select controls in a page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page where I have several input/select controls. All those controls use 'form-control and input-sm' css.

All I am looking for is, instead on applying both the css in each and every control separately, is there a better way to apply them globally in one place and all those controls inherit those css properties?

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/ebwwvy6m/1/

**HTML:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name 1</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name 2</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
</div>
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a wrapper and target every `input` and `select` tags inside it.

In this case the wrapper is `.form-group` but you can always wrap all the controls in a single element and use that in your CSS selector.

You will end with something like this combining both `.form-control` and `.input-sm` properties:

```
.form-group input,
.form-group select {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group select: focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
```

### Code Snippet:

```css
.form-group input,
.form-group select {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group select:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name 1</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name 2</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email address</label>
  <input type="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <select></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the classes "form-control" and "input-sm" always appear together in your document, here are two working options:

#### Case 1

If this is the only instance in which you use the class "form-group" or if you would like the same style applied to all child `input`/`select` elements, try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Name 1</label>
        <input type="text">   </div>   
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Name 2</label>
        <input type="text">   </div> 
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email">   </div>   
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password">   </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Gender</label>    
        <select></select>   
</div>
```

Then, in your **CSS**, change

```
.form-control {
  /* form-control class CSS Rules */
}

.input-sm {
  /* input-sm class CSS Rules */
}
```

to

```
.form-group input,
.form-group select {
  /* form-control class CSS Rules */
  /* input-sm class CSS Rules */
}
```

In CSS, a rule

```
.foo .bar {
  /* CSS Rules */
}
```

means that the CSS applies to any elements with the class name "bar" that are children of elements with a class name "foo".

#### Case 2

If there are other elements with the class name "form-group" that have child `input`/`select` elements that you would *not* like to take on these CSS rules, try this:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form_id">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name 1</label>
        <input type="text">   </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name 2</label>
        <input type="text">   </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email">   </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password">   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Gender</label>    
        <select></select>   
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#form_id input,
#form_id select {
  /* form-control class CSS Rules */
  /* input-sm class CSS Rules */
}
```

In this case, the CSS rules will only apply to the `input`/`select` elements that are children of an element with the ID "form_id".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCSS you can easily extend it to make form-control-sm the deafult:

```
.form-control {
   @extend .form-control-sm;
}
```